# Remove date from datatime index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, pandas-loc

I want to remove the date from datetime function in pandas and the following code works just fine.

```
df= pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df['Value']= df.Value.astype(float)
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.time
df.set_index('Time',inplace=True)
```

But after that when I try to select rows based on the time using .loc function it gives me the following error.

```
df_to_plot = df.loc['09:43:00':'13:54:00']

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'str'
```

But the same code works fine without .dt.time as follows:

```
df= pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df['Value']= df.Value.astype(float)
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df.set_index('Time',inplace=True)
df_to_plot = df.loc['2022-07-28 09:43':'2022-07-28 13:54']
```

How can I remove date and still select rows based on time?
Thank you.

Comment: Instead of `dt.time` you could consider using `dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")` to store the time values as strings instead of `datetime.time`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TypeError arrises because `df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.time` turns `df['Time']` into a `datetime.time` object, whereas in your `loc` statement, `'09:43:00':'13:54:00'` is a string.
Try this:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.time.astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `df.index = df.index.time`.

Comment: that would give an error, fyi

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).